# Apache HttpComponents code causing thread to block

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-httpcomponents

I am currently running a program that will download the source code from a website using Apache HttpComponents. I will be downloading a lot (10,000s) and so am using multiple threads to do this.

Sometimes all threads die (join) and sometimes they don't. Through debugging I have determined that the line

```
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget,context);
```

is the problem. Does anybody know how I can set a timeout for the this line, or why this line is blocking thread execution?

Comment: What connection manager are you using?  You should be using the PoolingClientConnectionManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be various reasons for threads getting stuck in an i/o operation, incorrect timeout settings being the most likely cause. One can set desired timeout values using `RequestConfig` class. However if all threads get blocked at once inside `#execute` method connection leak (connection pool depletion) would be more likely. Make sure that you *always* close CloseableHttpResponse instances even if do not care about the response or its content. You can find out more details about request execution by turning on wire / context logging as described in the [logging guide](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following timeout settings in [HttpConnectionParams](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/params/HttpConnectionParams.html) in my code (`HttpParams` are given to the `HttpClient` constructor):

```
org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(HttpParams, int)
org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(HttpParams, int)
```

A problem which I discovered when connecting to the same host with multiple threads, that blocking/timeouts occur when the `maxPerRoute` setting is lower than the number of threads. Have a look at [PoolingClientConnectionManager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html):

```
org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(int)
```